# How to get the minimum sales of a product without using GROUP BY and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to get the minimum sales of each product without using any GROUP BY and ROWNUM function. Just wondering how can I accomplish that. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: can you use window functions?

Comment: No without using any functions.

Comment: @SOaddict Why not?

Comment: Without using any functions I would like to solve this problem statement. I am fine to write the sql using group by and window functions but thats not what I need....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) product_id, sales
FROM mytable
ORDER BY product_id, sales;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT value,productid FROM 
table T1 
WHERE value=(select min(value) 
             from table t2 
             where t1.productid=t2.productid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table structure, this is impossible to answer correctly. But assuming your `orders` table has an `order_id` (PK), a `customer_id` and `sales` column, this should do it:

```
select o1.product_id, o1.sales
from orders o1
where o1.sales <= all (select o2.sales
                       from orders o2
                       where o2.product_id = o1.product_id
                         and o2.order_id <> o1.order_id);
```